# Volumes of solids bounded by surfaces

Tags: calculus, integration

Compute the volumes of solids bounded by the following surfaces:

$$x^2+y^2-2ax=0$$ $$ z=0$$ $$x^2+y^2=z^2$$

how can i solve this with multiple integrals i try changing variable but I got to $\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{a}}\sqrt{(r\cos\theta +a)^2+r^2\sin^2\theta}$ i can't solve it .

the answer from book is ${32\over 9 }a^3$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your change of coordinates might have been.  But here is what it looks like for me.

Convert to polar:

$x = r \cos \theta\\
y = r \sin \theta\\
z = z\\
dx\;dy\;dz = r\;dz\;dr\;d\theta$

Substitute into the original equations to find our limits.

$r^2 \cos^2 \theta + r^2 \sin^2\theta - 2ar \cos\theta =0\\
r = 2a\cos\theta$

Since this cylindar is to the right of the $y$ axis, $\theta$ from -$\frac \pi2$ to $\frac \pi 2$ is appropriate

$z = 0$

$r^2 \cos^2 \theta + r^2 \sin^2\theta = z^2\\
z = r$

$\int_{-\frac {\pi}{2}}^{\frac {\pi}{2}}\int_0^{2a\cos\theta}\int_0^r r\;dz\;dr\;d\theta$

Suppose you went

$x = r \cos \theta+a\\
y = r \sin \theta\\
z = z\\
dx\;dy\;dz = r\;dz\;dr\;d\theta$

$r = a$

$r^2 + 2ra\cos\theta + a^2= z^2$

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^{a}\int_0^{\sqrt{r^2+2ra\cos\theta+a^2}} r\;dz\;dr\;d\theta$

That looks close to what you have.

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^{a} r\sqrt{r^2+2ra\cos\theta+a^2}\;dr\;d\theta$

you dropped the Jacobian...but, this is indeed a messier intergral.